# How can I deal with parent class self.params using pytest?

Tags: mocking, pytest, patch, python-unittest

I am a newbie in testing, I mean, my previous tests were as simple as possible. 
Now I have a new duty to test complicated classes from time to time.
I spent a lot of time searching and reading different posts, documentation and questions, 
but it didn't help with some of the moments.
My question concerns self attributes of class (sometimes of parent class of testing class). 
I prepared a toy example for my question.
Simplified it looks like this.

Structure:

```
question
├── __init__.py
├── my_class.py
├── parent.py
└── test_classes
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_my_class.py
```

**my_class.py**

```
from question.parent import ParentClass


class MyClass(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self):
        self.param2 = 2

    def func1(self, some_param):
        self.param1 = 3
        # plenty of code
        important_value = self.param1 + some_param
        # more code
        some_result = important_value * 2
        return some_result
```

**parent.py**

```
class ParentClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.param1 = 1
        self.special = self.param2

    def func(self, smth):
       return smth
```

I suppose it is silly to rewrite the whole func1 to test in that manner:

**test_my_class.py**

```
from question.my_class import MyClass
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch

def new_func1(some_param):
    param1 = 3
    # plenty of code
    important_value = param1 + some_param
    # more code
    some_result = important_value * 2
    return some_result


class TestMyClass(TestCase):

    @patch.object(MyClass, 'func1', side_effect=new_func1)
    def test_func1(self, some_param):
        some_param = 1
        my_cl = MyClass()
        self.assertEqual(my_cl.func1(some_param), 8)
```

it works but it is not what I want. 
How can I mock self.param1 of the ParentClass?
I have to rewrite a lot and besides there are much more than one such param. 
It seems inefficient.
For testing ParentClass and deal with this awful self.special I patched  init, 
but it would be better to  mock just self.special.
It also seems that the dependency on ParentClass is lost. Do I need to change it?

Comment: You can simply assign the attribute via `my_cl.param1 = 100`, but I suspect this is not what you want?.. Do you want the mocking to circumvent the effects of the statement `self.param1 = 3` in `MyClass.func1`?

Comment: If only I could. The problem is that param1 is absent in MyClass, so it doesn't work (test is not passed with error). It was the first thing I tried btw.

Comment: But `param1` is set in the `ParentClass` in your example, so it is available. Your code in question is thus a bit misleading. Can you give a more relevant example?

Comment: I checked my code, and tried your advice in this very example, my_cl can take any new param in test if I don't use func1. For instance, this one is passed: `def test_again(self):
        my_cl = MyClass()
        my_cl.param5 = 3
        self.assertEqual(my_cl.param5, 3)` , but this one gives me TypeError: `test_more() missing 1 required positional argument 'some_param'` : `def test_more(self, some_param):
        some_param.return_result = 1
        my_cl = MyClass()
        my_cl.param1 = 3
        self.assertEqual(my_cl.func1(some_param), 8)`